# Read custom attributes of a file or folder in python

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, java-8, file-attributes

I set an attribute for a file/folder using Java's [`UserDefinedFileAttributeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html). Please find the code snippet as below:

```java
UserDefinedFileAttributeView userView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
userView.write("test", Charset.defaultCharset().encode("true"));
```

Now I want to read the attribute using Python.
I am able to read that attribute `test` using Java

Could someone guide me how to read this attribute using Python?

Comment: Did anyone found solution for this...